# How to Test a Specific Controller in MVC Core and User Interface?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, file-upload, controller

I created a section in my MVC website.
A code portion is embedded in particular section of the website. When the home page starts up, I have to navigate to login, go to, multiple different sections of website, before I reach upload files section. Is there any way to bypass this, to reach website portion directly, and test the file upload and user interface?

Is there any shortcut, or developer tricks to start particular portion of website for testing?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code to show? How does that code portion that you want to test look like etc..

Comment: well more of a shortcut question, how do I navigate straight away to page to test, without going through many other steps in website design